# In C++, what are the differences between static_cast<double>(a) and double(a)?

Tags: c++, casting

What are the differences between

```
int a;
// a gets some value
double pi = static_cast<double>(a)/3;
```

and

```
int a;
// a gets some value
double pi = double(a)/3;
```

Have you ever seen the latter? It seems to me I saw it in some snippet written by Stroustrup but I can't find the reference.

Comment: When `a` is an `int`, `static_cast<double>(a)`, `(double)a`, and `double(a)` are all semantically identical. The differences become evident when `a` is some other non-scalar type, or is `const` or `volatile`, etc.

Comment: @ildjarn and from a performance point of view?

Comment: Identical means identical -- there is no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @ildjarn: actually, won't `double(a)` be a bit (but insignificant) slower at compiling because it will first try to match a `const_cast`?

Comment: Answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/10077

Comment: @KillianDS : Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Finding static_cast<double> in your code is way easier. It stands out more.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Someone may have thought they were constructing rather than casting.  Consider:

```
some_fun(std::string("Hello"));
```

Many people think they're calling a constructor there when in fact they're doing a C-style cast.  It just so happens that casting will look at constructors of the target type among the long list of other things it looks at and so here it eventually ends up invoking the constructor.

Functional notation casts have all the same weaknesses of the other kind of C cast:

- Can inadvertently cast away constness
- Can silently turn into a reinterpret cast
- Are hard to differentiate with grepping tools.

Besides all that though, you're performing exactly the same operation in both cases.

Answer (score 11):

The latter is referred to as the *functional notation* of *explicit casting* where you explicitly say `a` should be treated as a `double`.  You can pretty much cast anything to any type using this technique.

The former is the preferred way to cast a type in C++.  It does basic checking to see that the type you are casting to makes sense (child class pointer to a base class pointer, etc.).  In addition, like in the example you show, you can perform implicit conversions.  Technically the `static_cast` in your example is explicit, but the result of the operation (the assignment) is implicit.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference in terms of generated assembly code between `static_cast<double> (a)` and `(double) a`. The key advantage of cast notation, `(type_id) cast_expression`, is that it is more flexible. In one situation it might be the equivalent of a `const_cast`, in another, a `static_cast`, in yet another, a `dynamic_cast`, in yet another, a combination of `const_cast` and `static_cast` (or `dynamic_cast`).

This strength is also a weakness. Cast notation means different things in different places. Another disadvantage is that it is very easy to find `xxx_cast<type_id> (cast_expression)`. Just search for `_cast`. It is very hard to find expressions that use cast notation.

Answer (score 2):

using static_cast is a safe C++-style way, but (double) - unsafe old C-style way.

see here: [Type Casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

Answer (score 1):

int a;

```
//This is the old way of converting a variable from its type to a double
double pi = double(a)/3;

//This is the new way of converting a variable from its type to a double
double pi = static_cast<double>(a)/3;
```

From Walter Savitch's book, (Problem Solving with CPP, 10th Edition) page 222