# Trouble with casting C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with casting; I have experience from Java where it is easy to cast and print:

```
int a = 1;
System.out.println((double)a);
```

and that code above will print 1.0.

In C++ this type of method don't work and I don't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a = 1;
    cout << (double)a;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, here my output is 1 and not 1.0 like I would expect.

Comment: I believe most implementations hide trailing zeroes. If you want a specific amount of digits theres some functions for that, just do a quick google search for it specifically.

Comment: this is more c than c++ answer, but try with printf("%.1f", (double)a);

Comment: @FrankS101 : An I heard somebody say don't c++, the c way ;)

Comment: Get out of the habit of using C-style (and Java-style I guess) casts and use proper C++style casts instead (if you really *have* to use a cast that is - usually best with a design where you don't need them at all). C-style casts are actively dangerous since it can perform many different casts and often some you don't really want - they are also hard to search for in code - searching for, for example, `static_cast` is much easier.

Comment: *can't understand why.* -- The reason is that Java is not C++.  Don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  Yes, there is similar syntax between the language, but don't be fooled into thinking you can take what you see in Java, and because there is something similar in C++ that looks like Java, expect to see the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting `cout` to use [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) notation, you can use [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) function to set precision of `cout` object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    cout << fixed            // setting notation
         << setprecision(1)  // setting precision
         << (double)a;       // print data
    return 0;
}
```

Output (stdout):

```
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify precision and fixed for cout output for floating point types. Put:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
```

before printing your doubles.

Fully working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a = 1;
   cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
   cout << (double)a << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it was declared as an int, would it still show the decimals?

Comment: The variable in OP is declared as an `int`. And the question is "_how to  easy to **cast** and print_".

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question - In that case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

To me it makes no sense to convert `int` to `double` because the fractional data will be lost once you write it against `int`. Moreover as stated by @Borgleader I guess the trailing zeroes are hidden in `C++`.

However you can convert a `float` or `double` to `int` or an `int` to `char` or vice versa using the same method which you showed in your code.

- In case of `float` or `double` to `int` , the fractional data will be lost
  i.e. `1.234` will become `1`.
- In case of `char` to `int` the resulting value will be the ASCII value of that character
  i.e. `A` will become `65` , `0` become `48` and in a vice versa situation `97` will become `a`.

Hope this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly do not specify the floating point formatting mode then  trailing zeros are not kept. It will be kept if you use the scientific mode or fixed mode. You can try to get the zeros like

```
 int a = 1;

  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(1);
  std::cout << (double)a << "\n";
```

[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/hfJGwR)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `static_cast<double>(a)`?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438249/in-c-what-are-the-differences-between-static-castdoublea-and-doublea

Answer (score -1):

You can convert it into a string if you are using C++11 or greater

```
std::string str = std::to_string (double(f));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't let you control the formatting, and will produce unnecessary trailing zeros. You can get rid of these by doing this:

```
str.erase (str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);
```

The one issue is that if you have "1.0" for example, it will produce "1."

Comment: Not the downvoter: but there's something called *efficiency*, you don't need to convert to a string manually to set precisions of floating point numbers in C++ streams.... again, this solution smells

Comment: Fair enough, I was just providing another way of doing it.