# Warnings when initialising map using std::uint8_t as key

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, literals

### Problem

I am trying to create a map of `std::uint8_t` ->  `char`, and initialise it with some values:

```
const std::map<std::uint8_t, char> ScenarioReader::alphabet = {
    { 0x12, 'b' },
    { 0x13, 'c' },
    { 0x15, 'a' },
    { 0x16, 'f' },
    ...
}
```

This generates a compiler warning because these integer literals (`0x12`, etc.) are recognised as `unsigned ints`, which are larger than a `std::uint8_t`:

```
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\utility(172): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from '_Ty' to '_Ty1', possible loss of data
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=unsigned int
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty1=uint8_t
1>        ]
1>d:\my-project\src\myfile.cpp(75): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<unsigned int,char,0>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=uint8_t,
1>            _Ty=char,
1>            _Other1=unsigned int,
1>            _Other2=char
1>        ]
1>d:\my-project\src\myfile.cpp(12): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<unsigned int,char,0>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=uint8_t,
1>            _Ty=char,
1>            _Other1=unsigned int,
1>            _Other2=char
1>        ]
```

### Solutions

I am aware of 2 possible ways to fix this:

#### 1) Disable warnings for this section

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4244 )
const std::map<std::uint8_t, char> ScenarioReader::alphabet = {
    { 0x12, 'b' },
    { 0x13, 'c' },
    { 0x15, 'a' },
    { 0x16, 'f' },
    ...
}
#pragma warning( pop)
```

#### 2) Cast every key explicitly

```
const std::map<std::uint8_t, char> ScenarioReader::alphabet = {
    { static_cast<std::uint8_t>(0x12), 'b' },
    { static_cast<std::uint8_t>(0x13), 'c' },
    { static_cast<std::uint8_t>(0x15), 'a' },
    { static_cast<std::uint8_t>(0x16), 'f' },
    ...
}
```

I am not particularly happy about either approach, but the second is especially ugly to me.

Am I, perhaps, missing a simpler solution?

Comment: Aaaand [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/fc5Yc5)

Comment: Disabling warnings is seldom useful. The second approach is the better one imo. Allthough it's big and ugly it expresses clearly what you are doing and that you know the cast to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) can never be an `std::uint8_t`. Instead of using a `static_cast`, you can make an [explicit cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) of the literal:

```
const std::map<std::uint8_t, char> alphabet = {
    { std::uint8_t(0x12), 'b' },
    { std::uint8_t(0x13), 'c' },
    { std::uint8_t(0x15), 'a' },
    { std::uint8_t(0x16), 'f' },
};
```

Comment: he could write a user-defined literal

Comment: You might think you are calling a constructor but this is a C-style cast  [...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438249/in-c-what-are-the-differences-between-static-castdoublea-and-doublea)

Comment: @AryanParekh no, that would be `(std::uint8_t)0x12`.

Comment: @AryanParekh Indeed, this is a cast and not a call to the constructor. I updated my answer accordingly. Finally, I think the use of a user-defined literal mentioned by JHBonarius seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Pierre, is the `std::` part in `std::uint8_t` really necessary? If you `#include <cstdint>` then you should have access to the type `uint8_t` without the namesame (I think behind the scenes there's a `typedef std::uint8_t uint8_t`).

Comment: @Elliott You can indeed remove the `std::` part.

Comment: @Pierre I also faced a situation where I needed to perform this. But I stuck to `static_cast` as it is safe

Comment: @Pierre I don't think it matters too much, but JHBonarius' method also teaches you some new things. Your method is just fine and that's why I upvoted

Answer (score 2):

You can write a user-define literal

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr std::uint8_t operator "" _ui8(unsigned long long value)
{
    return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(value);
}

#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(0x12_ui8), std::uint8_t>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is an erroneous one and it happens only on `\W4` warning level.

A conversion from a literal to `std::uint8_t` should not generate any warnings, unless the literal is out of range of the converted to type, which is not the case here.

Any option you choose is OK in my opinion. It just boils down to a matter of personal preference. I personally would prefer the `std::uint8_t{0x12}` syntax.

Another option would be to go down one warning level to `\W3` and then use a separate linter (`\W4` is mostly [used for lint-like warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019) anyway).